# Setting a member variable VS returning a value from a method

Tags: python, oop, theory

So `test` and `test2` do exactly the same thing, but the former does so by returning a value and the latter by setting a member variable.

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def do(self):
        val = self.doMore(5)
        print val

    def doMore(self, _v):
        return _v * _v


class test2:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def do(self):
        self.doMore(5)
        print self.val

    def doMore(self, _v):
        self.val = _v * _v
```

1. Which one is the right way to go and why?
2. Are there any performance differences when `val` gets bigger?

I'm wandering because sometimes I want to single out from a method a smaller task which is conceptually independent from the parent method; I feel like `test2` is more OOP, but on the other hand if the only method in the class to use the work of `doMore` is `do` I might as well save one member variable?

Comment: There is no `test1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do *not* do exactly the same thing.  In `test`, the result of `doMore` is ephemeral; once it is printed, it is gone.  But in `test2`, that value is part of the object, and stays part of it.  So if you don't need the value after it is printed, go with `test`; if you do, go with `test2`.